# Global jquery selectors not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to tidy some javascript/jquery code (not my forte).

I want to create some selectors that are available throughout the parent function, loanSelector.

I've included 2 sample functions that use the selectors.

1. Works
2. Returns [object object]

The jQuery object on the end is a slider.

Anyone got a clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
var loanSelector = function () {

    var local = {
        sliderAmount: $("#loan-selector .slider-amount")
    };

    // 1. This function returns the correct value
    function GetAmount() {
        return $("#loan-selector .slider-amount").slider("option", "value");
    }

    // 2. This function returns [object object]
    function GetAmount() {
        return local.sliderAmount.slider("option", "value");
    }

    // The caller
    function updatePaymentTerm(term) {
        updatePayment.call(this, GetAmount(), term);
    }

    // lots of other things happen down here
} ();
```

Comment: what is `sliderAmount` in `return local.sliderAmount.slider("option", "value");`?

Comment: That's the value of the jQuery ui slider

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this

Comment: @AgamBanga sample jsFiddle in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930986/global-jquery-selectors-not-working/43931704#43931704

Answer (score 0):

local is referencing the element ... $("#loan-selector .slider-amount")...  not the value of the element ..$("#loan-selector .slider-amount").val() ....

try this

```
var local = {
    sliderAmount: $("#loan-selector .slider-amount").val()
};
```

or reference the entire selector as the property of sliderAmount

```
var local = {
    sliderAmount: $("#loan-selector .slider-amount").slider("option", "value");
};


function GetAmount() {
    return local.sliderAmount
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tested both scenarios. The first one breaks thecode, the second still returns the [object object].

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jQuery are you using? Both functions seem to work as expected when using 3.2.1 (didn't try any other versions).

[Working example of sample below](https://jsfiddle.net/jessejjohnson/04ose7ts/1/)

**Sample**

```
$(function() {

  var loanSelector = function() {

    var local = {
      sliderAmount: $("#loan-selector .slider-amount")
    };

    function getResult1() {
      return $("#loan-selector .slider-amount").slider("option", "value");
    }

    function getResult2() {
      return local.sliderAmount.slider("option", "value");
    }

    var showResult1 = function() {
      var val1 = getResult1();
      $("#result-1").html(val1);
    }

    var showResult2 = function() {
      var val2 = getResult2();
      $("#result-2").html(val2);
    }

    return {
      showResult1,
      showResult2
    }

  }();

  // Setup slider
  $("#loan-selector .slider-amount").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    value: 250,
    slide: function(event, ui) {

      // Values after slider change
      loanSelector.showResult1();
      loanSelector.showResult2();

    }
  });

  // Initial values
  loanSelector.showResult1();
  loanSelector.showResult2();

});
```

Comment: I'm using jquery3 with a custom ui build

Comment: Well it's not the version - your code works back to 2.4.

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle.net demonstrating the issue would greatly increase your chances of a solution.